# Consuming Strapi API with Java - convert to Java objects

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a question about consuming webservices with JSON/Gson because my new webservice delivers other strings than my old webservice. My new webservice is generated by Strapi 4 and I have no possibility to change it.

My Java application worked with JSON strings like this from my old webservice:

```json
[
    {
        "nachname": "Studi1",
        "contactWebServiceDTO": [
            {
                "emailAddress": "studi1@xxx.de",
                "db_Id": 10,
                "dateCreated": "May 10, 2022 10:33:14 AM",
                "dateUpdated": "Feb 7, 2023 9:12:28 AM",
                "dtype": "Contact"
            }
        ],
        "db_Id": 792,
        "dateCreated": "Feb 26, 2021 2:11:19 PM",
        "dateUpdated": "May 6, 2022 10:01:02 AM",
        "dtype": "Person"
    }
]
```

I converted it into Java objects with Gson like this:

```java
JSONArray jsonArrayFromRest = new JSONArray(jsonString);

Gson gson = new Gson();
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
gson = builder.create();

if(identifiableWebServiceDTO instanceof PersonWebServiceDTO) {
    PersonWebServiceDTO personWebServiceDTO = new PersonWebServiceDTO();
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayFromRest.length(); i++) {
        String jsonObjectAsString = jsonArrayFromRest.getJSONObject(i).toString();
        personWebServiceDTO = gson.fromJson(jsonObjectAsString, PersonWebServiceDTO.class);
        dTOList.add(personWebServiceDTO);
    }
}
```

Corresponding classes are:

```
public class IdentifiableWebServiceDTO {

    protected long db_Id;

    protected Date dateCreated, dateUpdated;

    protected String dtype;

    //Getter, Setter...
}

public class PersonWebServiceDTO extends IdentifiableWebServiceDTO {

    private String nachname;

    private List<ContactWebServiceDTO> contactWebServiceDTO;

//  ...Setter/Getter

}

public class ContactWebServiceDTO extends IdentifiableWebServiceDTO {
    private String emailAddress = null;
    //Getter, Setter...
}
```

The new webservice delivers a string that nests every object in the string "data :[]" and the attributes in the string "attributes{}".

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Nicole",
                "createdAt": "2024-03-27T06:55:54.668Z",
                "updatedAt": "2024-03-27T06:56:18.843Z",
                "publishedAt": "2024-03-27T06:56:18.841Z",
                "mycontacts": {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "attributes": {
                                "address": "addressFromNicole",
                                "createdAt": "2024-03-27T06:56:09.438Z",
                                "updatedAt": "2024-03-27T06:56:11.625Z",
                                "publishedAt": "2024-03-27T06:56:11.619Z"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 2,
                            "attributes": {
                                "address": "secondAddressFromNicole",
                                "createdAt": "2024-03-27T06:56:40.962Z",
                                "updatedAt": "2024-03-27T06:56:41.709Z",
                                "publishedAt": "2024-03-27T06:56:41.706Z"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "pagination": {
            "page": 1,
            "pageSize": 25,
            "pageCount": 1,
            "total": 1
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have an idea how I can convert this structure into my old Java objects in a simple way?

Comment: Create new DTOs matching the new models, and adjust your code to use those new DTOs (or write/generate a mapper between the two models).